# Firing twice when swipeleft and swiperight in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I am new to jQuery mobile. I am using the swipe concept for swiping multiple separate html pages. It's working correctly when I come from swipepage3 to swipepage2. swipepage2 to swipepage1 and swipepage2 to swipepage3, It's firing twice. How to fix this issue?

Here is my code:

**Swipepage1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Share QR</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="slide.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="article1">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
  <h1>Countries</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="contentclass">
  <p>Newyork</p>
  <img src="img/newyork.jpg" style="height:460px;width:600px;"/>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>    
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Swipepage2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Share QR</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

<div data-role="page" id="article2">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
  <a href="swipepage1.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
  <h1>Countries</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="contentclass">
  <p>Seoul</p>
  <img src="img/seoul.jpg" style="height:460px;width:600px;"/>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
 </html>
```

**Swipepage3.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Share QR</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-sca le=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="article3">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
  <a href="swipepage1.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
  <h1>Countries</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="contentclass">
  <p>Capetown</p>
  <img src="img/capetown.jpg" style="height:460px;width:600px;"/>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
 </div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**slide.js**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function() {
$('#article1').bind('swipeleft', function(event,ui)
{
    $.mobile.changePage("swipepage2.html", "slide"); 
});



$('#article2').bind('swipeleft',  function(event,ui)
{
    $.mobile.changePage("swipepage3.html","slide");
});

$('#article2').bind('swiperight',  function()
{ 
    $.mobile.changePage("swipepage1.html","slide"); 
});



$('#article3').bind('swiperight', function(event,ui)
{ 
    $.mobile.changePage("swipepage2.html","slide"); 
});
});
```

Comment: replace `pagebeforecreate` with `pageinit` or `pageshow` and add this to remove binding on pagehide `$(document).on('pagehide', function () { $(this).off('swipeleft swiperight'); });`.

Comment: Thanks Omar we have tried and its working fine now...

Comment: @Ramasamy: Don't forget to post and validate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the events are getting bind twice for the page.

1.It is recommended to use .on() instead of .bind() 
I am using it outside of pagecreate/init/show and I am not facing any issues with .on
eg.

```
$('#article1').on('swipeleft', function(event,ui)
{
    $.mobile.changePage("swipepage2.html", "slide"); 
});
```