# Change page on swipeleft/swiperight

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, swipe

I have problem with mobile/tablet version of page which I create
I need this: When someone look at product detail and move him to right/left (touch/swipe) then I need load next/previous product detail (= Example: Now I on page with id=2 when I go right, then I load page with id=3, npw I on page with id=3 and I go left then I load page with id=2.. etc.. with different pages id).

I look in thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448137/firing-twice-when-swipeleft-and-swiperight-in-jquery-mobile), but this solution is not dynamic and I have problem applicate it. Next I inspirated in W3C [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp).

Now I have these codes which not work:

**JS file:**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {

    $('.epicFullscreen').bind('swipeleft',  function(event,ui)
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("http://www.some_domain.cz/category/page_name-1/","slide");
    });

    $('.epicFullscreen').bind('swiperight',  function()
    { 
        $.mobile.changePage("http://www.some_domain.cz/category/page_name-3/","slide"); 
    });

});
$(document).on('pagehide', function () { $(this).off('swipeleft swiperight'); });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <script src="funkce/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="funkce/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="funkce/skripty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I need use old JQuery 1.7.1. because this site using it and everything works fine, with newer JQuery I can have new problems. For that I use older JQuery-mobile 1.3.2. which must work with JQuery 1.7.1. ("jQuery Mobile 1.3 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer") . I can´t include "jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" because this styles not work together with my styles correctly.

**HTML in body is like that:**

```
<div class="epicFullscreen">
      <img class="epicImg" src="../../data_9/11normal.jpg" alt="inspirace č.2" title="inspirace č.2" border="0" />
  </div>
```

Now I have dynamic solution with arrows (right/left) and with adding correct urls with PHP, but on tablet/mobile user like using touch not clicking on arrows etc...

=> Where I have problem and why not work my current solution? And how I can change this static JS to dynamic JS?

Comment: first mistake, use jQuery 1.9.x. use `.one("pageinit", ...)` because this event will fire whenever a page is initinated.

Comment: I simply rewrite "$(document).on" to "$(document).one"? Is this thing work with JQuery 1.7.1. and some older Jquery-mobile or I must use jQuery 1.9.x ?

Comment: with jQM 1.3.2 you should use jQuery 1.9.1 or at least 1.8.3 You should get an error when using 1.7 "_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined_", check your console log.

Comment: I not have this error in console (I try it in Firebug in Firefox and in Google Chrome Canary), but I now try add "jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min" but nothing new still not work.

Comment: hmmm weird. Anyway `$.mobile.changePage("ULR", { transition: "slide" });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for that I make this answer. I simplify my problem and create simple page.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">-->
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

  var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
  var leva = $('#le').attr("href");
  var prava = $('#pr').attr("href");

  $("body").on("swiperight",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped right!");-->
    location.href=prava;
  });                       
  $("body").on("swipeleft",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped left!");-->
    location.href=leva;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="test_div" style="display: block;">
    <img src="test.gif" width="100px">
    <a id="le" href="http://www.some_domain.cz/category/page_name-1/">left</a>
    <a id="pr" href="http://www.some_domain.cz/category/page_name-3/">right</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this one hack - in PHP I know on which page I am, which page is before and which is next, I add this links it to arrows (which have tag "a"). This function working perfect. But I use this functional code to get correct URL => I don´t need some big function in JQuery which can split actual url with RegEx, know on which page I am, know if exist next page etc... Now I must only style this code to my page, but this is working.

I thank Omar for his time and I close this topic.

Comment: 2 days I can't accept my answer and close this topic. I wait on it.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple code .....

```
$(document).on("swipeleft", '#'+event.target.id, function () {
                        var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
                    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                        alert(nextpage.attr('id'));
                        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
                    }
                });

                $(document).on("swiperight", '#'+event.target.id, function () {
                    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
                    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, { transition: "slide", reverse:           true }, true, true);
                        }
                    });
```